# Can write an application with Symfony2 without using any ORM for data access?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to choose a MVC framework for a special kind of project. I've chosen Symnfony2 but there is something that make me worried. I don't wanna use any ORM and I would prefer to use raw `SQL` queries.

Is it possible with Symfony2?

Comment: Yes you can, I never used ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind you can write your own SQL queries in symfony2

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
'SELECT p
FROM AppBundle:Product p
WHERE p.price > :price
ORDER BY p.price ASC'
)->setParameter('price', '19.99');

$products = $query->getResult();
// to get just one result:
// $product = $query->setMaxResults(1)->getOneOrNullResult();
```

You just need to understand a little bit the syntax, and the Entity namin convention

I strongly recommend reading the cookbook for a fast learning

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall a DoctrineBundle and write your DB logic how you want. But in this way you should write a lot of custom things for example user provider for authentication. And a huge number of community bundles were based on doctrine.